# Change default credentials in Tee-clc. MacOS

Tags: macos, team-explorer-everywhere

I installed tee-clc 14.135 using brew install on MacOS Catalina. I set it up with my credentials that were saved and every time I do checkin it uses those credentials.

`tf checkin`
`Access denied connecting to TFS server http:severname:8080/ (authenticating as UserName/DomainName)`

I need to substitute cached credentials with the new ones. Any ideas how to do so?

I tried:
`export TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS=1` and using different credentials.
Uninstalling tee-clc didn't help. Still picks up old credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I need to substitute cached credentials with the new ones.

You could clear mac cached credentials by reference to [Password, Credential Manager and Keychain Editing](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fanswers.uillinois.edu%2Fillinois%2Fpage.php%3Fid%3D68546&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cfae82a16f787426f6e2108d8b910fc6d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637462829894063707%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=liMqpC4nj7RU52MOg%2B0SQtbzxGZ%2F24Zec0mZ36ISPZI%3D&reserved=0) for guidance.

If you use Eclipse, please close all Eclipse instances, clear TFS/DevOps caches **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache**, and restart the Eclipse as Administrator.

If you use Visual Studio, please refer to this thread: [Clear stored TFS credentials in Visual Studio](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F47198510%2F14886002&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cfae82a16f787426f6e2108d8b910fc6d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637462829894073702%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=U9EQfXeWJOob7B%2B86WkBfmURuml8Z2sNGy2QPO8SX7s%3D&reserved=0) for more details.

In addition, if your organization is secured with a firewall or proxy server, please refer to this doc: [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsecurity%2Fallow-list-ip-url%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-2020&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cfae82a16f787426f6e2108d8b910fc6d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637462829894073702%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=k3Z1uv89ucCWHCVx7YqC0IrtSsuyeyBglPT9f86Itro%3D&reserved=0) to configure your Network environment.

BYW, this [thread](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmicrosoft%2Fazure-repos-vscode%2Fissues%2F352&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cfae82a16f787426f6e2108d8b910fc6d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637462829894083701%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=Wmm5t2Xhrcv88yWDDtISi6oqrHs3EI4%2FFpP5B5yC69E%3D&reserved=0) talks more about this issue, might be helpful too.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!